# How to return the results of MySQL's aggregated function using c#?

Tags: c#, aggregate-functions

I am trying to write a genertic method that will allow me to return the the value of an aggregated function `(ie. COUNT(), MAX(), MIN())`

The problem is the `MIN()/MAX()` can return a `datetime, date, decimal, int.` So I want to be able to handle all the values. I need this number to return only one value not multiple columns.

How can I make this method return any values?

```
    // query the data base
    public IEnumerable<T> getValue<T>(string query, List<MySqlParameter> pars)
    {
        double value;
        using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(conn_string))
        using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn))
        {

            if (pars != null)
            {
                foreach (MySqlParameter p in pars)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
                }
            }

            conn.Open();
            try
            {
                value = Convert.ToDouble(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

            } catch(Exception ex){

                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "SQL Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                value = -1;

            } finally {
                conn.Close();
            }

        }

        return value;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare `value` as `T` and cast the result of `ExecuteScalar` to `T`.

```
T value;
// ...
try
{
     value = (T)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
} 
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "SQL Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    value = default(T);

}
finally 
{
     conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error at `return value;`  `Cannot implicitly convert type 'T' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)` Also, what does `default(T)` do?

Comment: @Mike you need to change return type as T. default(T) give you the default value based on type. if it's a reference type it returns null, if value type it sets all members to their default values.

Comment: I get an error when trying to use it. here is how I am using it `int cnt = (int)(db.getValue(sSQL, parms1));` and I am passing a COUNT(*) function `Error 1 The type arguments for method 'POS.dbConnetion.getValue<T>(string, System.Collections.Generic.List<MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly`

Answer (score 1):

```
public T getValue<T>(string query, List<SqlParameter> param) {

    // your existing code

    object value = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

    // This line will change the to the right type. You still need to handle null
    // and various Nullable type if you use these
    return Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
}

// to use
int cnt = getValue<int>(query, params);
```

Comment: Thank you. I get an error when trying to use the method. here is how I am using it int cnt = (int)db.getValue(sSQL, parms1); and I am passing a COUNT(*) function Error 1 The type arguments for method 'POS.dbConnetion.getValue<T>(string, System.Collections.Generic.List<MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly

Comment: See the updated code. Note that the return is now T and not IEmunerable<T>

Comment: That corrected the error but not I get SQL Error System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not value ....getValue[T](String query, List 1 pars)....